# How can we add 2 other activities in Manifest file?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I want to go to two other activities from the Main activity itself.
how can I add them in manifest file such that two activities can be opened at a time from main activity?

Comment: no I want add two activities  at a time that too from the MainActivity itself

Comment: What do you mean "at a time"? Only one activity can be on the screen at a time.

Answer (score 1):

This is how your Manifest could look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.yourdomain">

    <application
        android:name=".App">

        <activity
            android:name=".path.to.your.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".path.to.your.SecondActivity"/>

         <activity
            android:name=".path.to.your.ThirdActivity"/>
        
         <!-- add more activities if you like -->  

    </application>

</manifest>
```

More documentation: [App Manifest Overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro)